# Alguien sabe porque me sale este eror al querer crear una llave ssh en git

Tags: git, github

$ ssh-xxxxxx-x 000000-sk -x "123123@mail.com"
Generating public/private ed25519-sk key pair.
You may need to touch your authenticator to authorize key generation.
Key enrollment failed: invalid format

Comment: Yo etiquetaría con `ssh` en vez de `git`.

Comment: ¿Qué comando estás usando? No reconozco ese patrón ssh-xxxxxx-x

Comment: es un comando que me dio git para poderle dar acceso o una llave a mi pc, solo que cambie los valores por equis xd. y coloque el correo de la cuenta que tengo en git, pero aun asi no funciona:c y me aparece ese error

Comment: ¿No debería ser `ssh-keygen`? No sé qué tipo de comando puede ser ssh-xxxxxx ni aún cambiando las x por "valores".